# How to display the comment_form with a shortcode while removing it from its default position?

Tags: shortcode, comment-form

I was already able to have the comments form show in the post content area with this code, which allows me to use the [wpsites_comment_form] shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'wpsites_comment_form', 'wpsites_comment_form_shortcode' );
function wpsites_comment_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    comment_form();
    $cform = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $cform;
}
```

What I need is to remove the comments form from the bottom of the post (default display). When I remove it through the admin panel in Posts - Edit - Comments - Don't Allow, it is also removed from the location where it displayed through the shortcode function. So how can I make it display only where the shortcode is placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Version #1

The following seems to work for the *Twenty Fifteen* theme:

```
/**
 * Display the comment form via shortcode on singular pages
 * Remove the default comment form.
 * Hide the unwanted "Comments are closed" message with CSS.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177289/26350
 */

add_shortcode( 'wpse_comment_form', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comment_form();
        print(  '<style>.no-comments { display: none; }</style>' );
        add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );
```

where we only allow the shortcode to display the comment form on singular posts that support comments.

Here we use CSS to hide the unwanted *Comments are closed* message.

### Version #2

Here's another approach without CSS:

```
/**
 * Display the comment form via shortcode on singular pages.
 * Remove the default comment form.
 * Hide the unwanted "Comments are closed" message through filters.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177289/26350
 */

add_shortcode( 'wpse_comment_form', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comment_form();
        add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse_comment_form_defaults' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }           
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );

function wpse_comment_form_defaults( $defaults )
{
    add_filter( 'comments_open', 'wpse_comments_open' );
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return $defaults;
}

function wpse_comments_open( $open )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Version #1 tested and it works with the theme I'm using. great!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you @rodrigonomada

Comment: If I want to bring also de list of comments (comments_template) to be displayed above the form, I would need another shortcode function for it? Is it a similar approach?

Comment: I found something here, but am not sure I know how to apply it:
http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2011-April/038832.html

Comment: I tried to mimic birgire's "Version #1" shared above in the answer in order to display the list of comments above the comment_form. It worked partially. It displays the comments in the default location (bottom) also.

I used this:
`add_shortcode( 'wpse_comments_template', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comments_template();
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );`

Comment: I reposted this second question beyond these comments and maybe I've reached a solution, even though it might not be the best way. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593898/how-to-display-the-comments-template-with-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/28594128

Comment: ok great, didn't have time to check it out, will try to have a look tomorrow @rodrigonomada

Comment: I managed to arrive at the result that I needed but partly through deleting on my child-theme the parts that I couldn't remove through code. I removed the comments_template() call from single.php and removed the comments_form() call from the comments.php (otherwise it would show where I use the shortcode to display the Comments list) I wonder if there are negative aspects of doing it this way rather then filtering them out through the functions.php file? @birgire