# Hide Post comments when displayed via WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, shortcode, comments

I've written a shortcode which displays 'x' number of posts on the homepage of my site when I write `[blog posts_per_page-"3"]`. Here it is:

```
function getBlogPosts($atts) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "posts_per_page" => '',
  ), $atts));

  $queryArgs = array(
    "posts_per_page" => $posts_per_page
  );

  $queryPosts = new WP_Query($queryArgs);
  $output = "";

  $output .= "<ul class='articles-list clearfix'>";

    if ( $queryPosts->have_posts() ) : while ( $queryPosts->have_posts() ) : $queryPosts->the_post();
      $output .= "<li class='clearfix ind-article'>
        <a class='article-container' href='". get_the_permalink() ."'>";
        if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium'); // medium img size = 300x300. => make sure photos uploaded are at least 600x600
        }
        $output .= "<div class='article-content'>";
          $output .= "<h3 class='entry-title gamma uppercase'>". get_the_title() ."</h3>";
          $output .= "<span class='entry-meta'>". get_the_date('l jS F') ."</span>";
      $output .= "</div></a></li>";
    endwhile; endif;

  $output .= "</ul>";

  return $output;
} add_shortcode('blog', 'getBlogPosts');
```

However, when I do this, a comment form for the blog post is also displayed (it's definitely the post's comment form, not the page - also seems to only be one comment form, for the last blog post displayed I think). I want to keep comments enabled but remove the comment from when the shortcode is used. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You must remember to call the core function `wp_reset_postdata()`, after your *while* loop, to restore the global `$post` object. The comment form is relying on that object, that you override with your `$queryPosts->the_post()` call.

Note that the `extract()` isn't recommended, check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/26350) by @toscho, for example.

### Removing comments

To remove the *comment form*, when using a shortcode, you could check out my [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177234/how-to-display-the-comment-form-with-a-shortcode-while-removing-it-from-its-defa).

If you want to remove the *list of comments* and the *comment-form*, after the shortcode, then you can try out one the following methods, within the shortcode's callback:

**Method #1** Remove the queried comments via filters:

```
if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
{
    // Remove the comment form
    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' ); 

    // Remove the list of comments
    add_filter( 'comments_array', '__return_empty_array' );
}
```

**Method #2** Force `get_comments()` to return an empty array:

```
if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
{
    // Remove the comment form
    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );

    // Empty comments SQL query - Run only once
    add_filter( 'comments_clauses', function( $clauses )
    {
        static $count = 0;
        if( 0 === $count++ )
            $clauses['where'] .= ' AND 1=0 ';
        return $clauses;
     });
}
```

Here we run the filter callback only once, to prevent this from e.g. a *recent comments* widget in the sidebar.

**Method #3** Modify the *comment template* via filter. Create an empty file `comments-empty.php` within your theme and use:

```
if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
{
    // Modify the comment template
    add_filter( 'comments_template', function( $template )   
    {
        if( $tmp = locate_template( 'comments-empty.php' ) )
            $template = $tmp;
        return $template;
    } );
}
```

You can modify the file path to your needs.

**Method #4** Hide it with CSS. Example:

```
if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
{
    print '<style> #comments { display: none } </style>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and many different ways of doing it! I used method 1 which seemed to work. Also thanks for the tips about `wp_reset_postdata()` (I always forget it) and the `extract()` stuff. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just fixed a typo in method #1. @TomOakley